# How to change value of object which is inside an array using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The code below comes from jQuery UI Autocomplete:

```js
var projects = [
    {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
    },
    {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
    },
    {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
    }
];
```

For example, I want to change the **desc value of jquery-ui**. How can I do that?

Additionally, is there a faster way to get the data? I mean give the object a name to fetch its data, just like the object inside an array? So it would be something like `jquery-ui.jquery-ui.desc = ....`

Comment: You would have to transform the array into a Javascript object in order to use the syntax `projects["jquery-ui"].desc`. Would that be worth the effort only to get nicer syntax?

Comment: I've updated my solution with your latest question. And you can use the "projects.jquery-ui.desc" notation.

Comment: **  ↑ aston means you can use that notation if the object structure is changed as per his answer below. (*Not* with the OP's existing example structure.)

Comment: For new people, just use `.find()` it's a method for the array and is very useful in this case. See [abe kur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45194601/11224924) on this.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

You have to search in the array like:

```
function changeDesc( value, desc ) {
   for (var i in projects) {
     if (projects[i].value == value) {
        projects[i].desc = desc;
        break; //Stop this loop, we found it!
     }
   }
}
```

and use it like

```
var projects = [ ... ];
changeDesc ( 'jquery-ui', 'new description' );
```

**UPDATE:**

To get it faster:

```
var projects = {
   jqueryUi : {
      value:  'lol1',
      desc:   'lol2'
   }
};

projects.jqueryUi.desc = 'new string';
```

(In according to Frédéric's comment you shouldn't use hyphen in the object key, or you should use "jquery-ui" and projects["jquery-ui"] notation.)

Comment: Is there much faster way to get the data? I mean give the object a name to fetch its data.Just like the object inside array.So,can I used in that way : jquery-ui.jquery-ui.desc = ....

Comment: your update won't work because of the hyphen `-` in the object name. You would have to write `"jquery-ui": {}` and `projects["jquery-ui"].desc` respectively.

Comment: look at the abe kur's  answer, that is the right, this and anothers are long

Comment: For new people, just use `.find()` it's a method for the array and is very useful in this case. See [abe kur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45194601/11224924) on this.

Answer (score 566):

It is quite simple

- Find the index of the object using `findIndex` method.
- Store the index in variable.
- Do a simple update like this: `yourArray[indexThatyouFind]`

```js
//Initailize array of objects.
let myArray = [
  {id: 0, name: "Jhon"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
],
    
//Find index of specific object using findIndex method.    
objIndex = myArray.findIndex(obj => obj.id == 1);

//Log object to Console.
console.log("Before update: ", myArray[objIndex])

//Update object's name property.
myArray[objIndex].name = "Laila"

//Log object to console again.
console.log("After update: ", myArray[objIndex])
```

Comment: it will mutate myArray.

Comment: Yes, But if you do not want to mutate. ```[...myArray.slice(0, objIndex), Object.assign({}, myArray[objIndex], myArray.slice(objIndex + 1))]```

Comment: @UmairAhmed Shouldnt the above code be 
`[...myArray.slice(0, objIndex), Object.assign({}, myArray[objIndex], ...myArray.slice(objIndex + 1))]` ?

I think ur missing the second ellipses.

Comment: In my case it's perfect, I was looking for a way to get an object into an object array, then change one of its properties. I need the object to mutate because it's watched by a Vue.js component

Answer (score 192):

The best solution, thanks to ES6.

This returns a new array with a replaced description for the object that contains a value equal to "jquery-ui".

```
const newProjects = projects.map(p =>
  p.value === 'jquery-ui'
    ? { ...p, desc: 'new description' }
    : p
);
```

Comment: @FrederikoCesar not in all cases, iterating over each object costs more than slicing the array and inject the new object using spread operator

Comment: what if you want to change the value on the fly? Without creating another var?  Best way is the index method: const targetIndex = summerFruits.findIndex(f=>f.id===3);

Comment: this is great and short. could you write out how you would update two values at the same time from the? the shorthand notation is sure hard to understand for me. ? : are if else whats "..."

Comment: @SgtPepperAut maybe this way: `proj.map(p => ['jquery-ui', 'other-value'].includes(p.value) ? { ...p, desc: 'new-description' } : p )`

Comment: For new people, just use `.find()` it's a method for the array and is very useful in this case. See [abe kur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45194601/11224924) on this.

Comment: This is pretty good, but it will go over the entire array, even after finding/updating the item. For a short array is great, but if it becomes too big, findIndex might be better.

Comment: I really enjoyed this answer and made sure to remember it after applying it to my code. It is similar to what I have done before, but now that I am using the spread operator as a first instinct, this is the clean way of altering an object in an array in a single statement! Bravo Kintaro!

Answer (score 105):

Using map is the best solution without using extra libraries.(using ES6)

```
const state = [
{
    userId: 1,
    id: 100,
    title: "delectus aut autem",
    completed: false
},
{
    userId: 1,
    id: 101,
    title: "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    completed: false
},
{
    userId: 1,
    id: 102,
    title: "fugiat veniam minus",
    completed: false
},
{
    userId: 1,
    id: 103,
    title: "et porro tempora",
    completed: true
}]

const newState = state.map(obj =>
    obj.id === "101" ? { ...obj, completed: true } : obj
);
```

Comment: this solution was provided already: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51718190/6543875

Comment: This solution only works when ternary operator is used. Isn't is possible to use this method without ternary operator like --> `const newState = state.map(obj =>
   [{ ...obj, completed: true }]
);`   ?

Answer (score 95):

**ES6** way, without **mutating** original data.

```
var projects = [
{
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
},
{
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
}];

//find the index of object from array that you want to update
const objIndex = projects.findIndex(obj => obj.value === 'jquery-ui');

// Make sure to avoid incorrect replacement
// When specific item is not found
if (objIndex === -1) {
  return;
}

// make new object of updated object.   
const updatedObj = { ...projects[objIndex], desc: 'updated desc value'};

// make final new array of objects by combining updated object.
const updatedProjects = [
  ...projects.slice(0, objIndex),
  updatedObj,
  ...projects.slice(objIndex + 1),
];

console.log("original data=", projects);
console.log("updated data=", updatedProjects);
```

Answer (score 37):

You can use [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over the array and locate the object you're interested in:

```
$.each(projects, function() {
    if (this.value == "jquery-ui") {
        this.desc = "Your new description";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 24):

given the following data, we want to replace *berries* in the `summerFruits` list with *watermelon*.

```
const summerFruits = [
{id:1,name:'apple'}, 
{id:2, name:'orange'}, 
{id:3, name: 'berries'}];

const fruit = {id:3, name: 'watermelon'};
```

Two ways you can do this.

First approach:

```
//create a copy of summer fruits.
const summerFruitsCopy = [...summerFruits];

//find index of item to be replaced
const targetIndex = summerFruits.findIndex(f=>f.id===3); 

//replace the object with a new one.
summerFruitsCopy[targetIndex] = fruit;
```

Second approach: using `map`, and `spread`:

```
const summerFruitsCopy = summerFruits.map(fruitItem => 
fruitItem .id === fruit.id ? 
    {...summerFruits, ...fruit} : fruitItem );
```

`summerFruitsCopy` list will now return an array with updated object.

Comment: The first method is best. No need to move to another var and then back. On the fly method. I up voted your solution.

Answer (score 23):

you can use .find so in your example

```
   var projects = [
            {
                value: "jquery",
                label: "jQuery",
                desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
                icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
            },
            {
                value: "jquery-ui",
                label: "jQuery UI",
                desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
                icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
            },
            {
                value: "sizzlejs",
                label: "Sizzle JS",
                desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
                icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
            }
        ];

let project = projects.find((p) => {
    return p.value === 'jquery-ui';
});

project.desc = 'your value'
```

Comment: While this functionally does the same thing, `findIndex` performs significantly better than `find`. If your source array is large, I recommend `findIndex` instead. Refer to the answer with the most upvotes.

Answer (score 22):

It's easily can be accomplished with underscore/lodash library:

```
  _.chain(projects)
   .find({value:"jquery-ui"})
   .merge({desc: "new desc"}).value();
```

Docs: 
https://lodash.com/docs#find 
https://lodash.com/docs#merge

Comment: What if 'jquery-ui' is not found by the find function?

Comment: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'LoDashExplicitArrayWrapper'

Comment: The result of such sequences must be unwrapped with _#value. https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chain

`.value()`

Answer (score 20):

This is another answer involving `find`.
This relies on the fact that `find`:

- iterates through every object in the array UNTIL a match is found
- each object is provided to you and is MODIFIABLE

Here's the critical Javascript snippet:

```
projects.find( function (p) {
    if (p.value !== 'jquery-ui') return false;
    p.desc = 'your value';
    return true;
} );
```

Here's an alternate version of the same Javascript:

```
projects.find( function (p) {
    if (p.value === 'jquery-ui') {
        p.desc = 'your value';
        return true;
    }
    return false;
} );
```

Here's an even shorter (and somewhat more evil version):

```
projects.find( p => p.value === 'jquery-ui' && ( p.desc = 'your value', true ) );
```

Here's a full working version:

```js
  let projects = [
            {
                value: "jquery",
                label: "jQuery",
                desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
                icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
            },
            {
                value: "jquery-ui",
                label: "jQuery UI",
                desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
                icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
            },
            {
                value: "sizzlejs",
                label: "Sizzle JS",
                desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
                icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
            }
        ];

projects.find( p => p.value === 'jquery-ui' && ( p.desc = 'your value', true ) );

console.log( JSON.stringify( projects, undefined, 2 ) );
```

Comment: Wow, this is some piece of magic you just did there!

Answer (score 19):

you need to know the index of the object you are changing. then its pretty simple

```
projects[1].desc= "new string";
```

Answer (score 19):

```js
const users = [
  { name: "Alex", age: 25 },
  { name: "John", age: 32 },
];

const newUsers = users.map((user) => ({
  ...user,
  age: user.age + 5, // just for example
}));

// newUsers = [
// {name:"Alex" , age:30},
// {name:"John , age:37}
// ]
```

Comment: somehow missing the () after the arrow function raised an error for me so this one looks to be the most correct answer for ES6

Answer (score 13):

I think this way is better

```
const index = projects.findIndex(project => project.value==='jquery-ui');
projects[index].desc = "updated desc";
```

Comment: in your `findIndex` you're assigning a value instead of comparing

Answer (score 8):

```
let users = [
    {id: 1, name: 'Benedict'},
    {id: 2, name: 'Myles'},
    {id: 3, name: 'Happy'},
]

 users.map((user, index) => {
 if(user.id === 1){
  users[index] = {id: 1, name: 'Baba Benny'};    
 }
 
 return user
})


console.log(users)
```

What this code does is map over the object and then match the desired
with *if statement*,

```
if(user.id === 1)
```

once there is match somewhere use its index to swap

```
 users[index] = {id: 1, name: 'Baba Benny'};
```

the object in the array  and then return the modified array

Comment: instead of writing the code, please explain what is happening there

Comment: There’s 29 answers already. The accepted answer has 183 upvotes. Why do we need another answer? What is this answer offering that’s not already covered by the previous 29 answers?

Comment: @JeremyCaney  This is because there so many ways to skin a cat, also by provide readers with verities of code flow they can pick one or mix and match the approaches

Comment: @mwangaben return value will be user, not users

Comment: @sayinmehmet47 thanks for pointing it out i have already fixed

Answer (score 5):

Change value with conditions using for each loop

```
projects.forEach((p,index)=>{
    if(index === 1){
       p.value = "Updated jquery-ui"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
// using higher-order functions to avoiding mutation
var projects = [
            {
                value: "jquery",
                label: "jQuery",
                desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
                icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
            },
            {
                value: "jquery-ui",
                label: "jQuery UI",
                desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
                icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
            },
            {
                value: "sizzlejs",
                label: "Sizzle JS",
                desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
                icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
            }
        ];

// using higher-order functions to avoiding mutation
index = projects.findIndex(x => x.value === 'jquery-ui');
[... projects.slice(0,index), {'x': 'xxxx'}, ...projects.slice(index + 1, projects.length)];
```

Comment: this `...` before projects are necessary?

Comment: @lazzy_ms the `...` is known as the spread operator. google it :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use map function --

```
const answers = this.state.answers.map(answer => {
  if(answer.id === id) return { id: id, value: e.target.value }
  return answer
})

this.setState({ answers: answers })
```

Answer (score 4):

try using `forEach(item,index)` helper

```
var projects = [
    {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
    },
    {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
    },
    {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
    }
];

let search_to_change = 'jquery'

projects.forEach((item,index)=>{
   if(item.value == search_to_change )
      projects[index].desc = 'your description ' 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice neat clear answer. I wasn't 100% sure this would work but it seems to be fine. Please let me know if a lib is required for this, but I don't think one is. Also if this doesn't work in x browser please let me know. I tried this in Chrome IE11 and Edge they all seemed to work fine.

```
    var Students = [
        { ID: 1, FName: "Ajay", LName: "Test1", Age: 20},
        { ID: 2, FName: "Jack", LName: "Test2", Age: 21},
        { ID: 3, FName: "John", LName: "Test3", age: 22},
        { ID: 4, FName: "Steve", LName: "Test4", Age: 22}
    ]

    Students.forEach(function (Student) {
        if (Student.LName == 'Test1') {
            Student.LName = 'Smith'
        }
        if (Student.LName == 'Test2') {
            Student.LName = 'Black'
        }
    });

    Students.forEach(function (Student) {
        document.write(Student.FName + " " + Student.LName + "<BR>");
    });
```

Output should be as follows

Ajay Smith

Jack Black

John Test3

Steve Test4

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you wanted to run a bit more complicated codes during the modification, you might reach for an if-else statement over the ternary operator approach

```
// original 'projects' array;
var projects = [
    {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
    },
    {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
    },
    {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
    }
];
```

```
// modify original 'projects' array, and save modified array into 'projects' variable
projects = projects.map(project => {
// When there's an object where key 'value' has value 'jquery-ui'
    if (project.value == 'jquery-ui') {

// do stuff and set a new value for where object's key is 'value'
        project.value = 'updated value';

// do more stuff and also set a new value for where the object's key is 'label', etc.
        project.label = 'updated label';

// now return modified object
        return project;
    } else {
// just return object as is
        return project;
    }
});

// log modified 'projects' array
console.log(projects);
```

Answer (score 2):

We can change in the following way

```
const oldArray = [{username: gopal, age: 20}, {username: gopi, age: 21}]
const obj = {username: gopal, age: 25}
const result = oldArray.map(d => d.username === 'gopi' ? d.age = obj.age : d)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use Array's map function to modify object of an array using Javascript.

```
function changeDesc(value, desc){
   projects.map((project) => project.value == value ? project.desc = desc : null)
}

changeDesc('jquery', 'new description')
```

Comment: this will return [null, object with the updated value, null]

Answer (score 1):

The power of javascript destructuring

```js
const projects = [
  {
    value: 'jquery',
    label: 'jQuery',
    desc: 'the write less, do more, JavaScript library',
    icon: 'jquery_32x32.png',
    anotherObj: {
      value: 'jquery',
      label: 'jQuery',
      desc: 'the write less, do more, JavaScript library',
      icon: 'jquery_32x32.png',
    },
  },
  {
    value: 'jquery-ui',
    label: 'jQuery UI',
    desc: 'the official user interface library for jQuery',
    icon: 'jqueryui_32x32.png',
  },
  {
    value: 'sizzlejs',
    label: 'Sizzle JS',
    desc: 'a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine',
    icon: 'sizzlejs_32x32.png',
  },
];

function createNewDate(date) {
  const newDate = [];
  date.map((obj, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      newDate.push({
        ...obj,
        value: 'Jquery??',
        label: 'Jquery is not that good',
        anotherObj: {
          ...obj.anotherObj,
          value: 'Javascript',
          label: 'Javascript',
          desc: 'Write more!!! do more!! with JavaScript',
          icon: 'javascript_4kx4k.4kimage',
        },
      });
    } else {
      newDate.push({
        ...obj,
      });
    }
  });

  return newDate;
}

console.log(createNewDate(projects));
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the index first:

```
function getIndex(array, key, value) {
        var found = false;
        var i = 0;
        while (i<array.length && !found) {
          if (array[i][key]==value) {
            found = true;
            return i;
          }
          i++;
        }
      }
```

Then:

```
console.log(getIndex($scope.rides, "_id", id));
```

Then do what you want with this index, like:

$scope[returnedindex].someKey = "someValue";

Note: please do not use for, since for will check all the array documents, use while with a stopper, so it will stop once it is found, thus faster code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your specific function like the below, then use that everywhere you need.

```
var each    = (arr, func) => 
                Array.from(
                    (function* (){
                        var i = 0;
                        for(var item of arr)
                            yield func(item, i++);
                    })()
                );
```

Enjoy..

Comment: Welcome to the community, if you explain what is going on and how it is working, then obviously everyone can `Enjoy..`

Answer (score 0):

```js
upsert(array, item) { 
        const i = array.findIndex(_item => _item.id === item.id);
        if (i > -1) {
            let result = array.filter(obj => obj.id !== item.id);
            return [...result, item]
        }
        else {
            return [...array, item]
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var projects = [
    {
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
    },
    {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
    },
    {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
    }
];

// Change the value of the second object in the array
projects[1].value = "new value"; // Change "jquery-ui" to "new value"

// Alternatively, change the value where label is "jQuery" to "new value"
projects.forEach(function(project) {
    if (project.label === "jQuery") {
        project.value = "new value";
    }
});

// Output the updated projects array
console.log(projects);
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    value: 'jquery',
    label: 'jQuery',
    desc: 'the write less, do more, JavaScript library',
    icon: 'jquery_32x32.png'
  },
  {
    value: 'new value',  // The value has been changed to "new value"
    label: 'jQuery UI',
    desc: 'the official user interface library for jQuery',
    icon: 'jqueryui_32x32.png'
  },
  {
    value: 'sizzlejs',
    label: 'Sizzle JS',
    desc: 'a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine',
    icon: 'sizzlejs_32x32.png'
  }
]
```

Answer (score -1):

to update multiple items with the matches use:

```
_.chain(projects).map(item => {
      item.desc = item.value === "jquery-ui" ? "new desc" : item.desc;
      return item;
    })
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. it uses jQuery grep function

```
array = $.grep(array, function (a) {
    if (a.Id == id) {
        a.Value= newValue;
    }
    return a;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here i am using angular js. In javascript you can use for loop to find.

```
    if($scope.bechval>0 &&$scope.bechval!=undefined)
    {

                angular.forEach($scope.model.benhmarkghamlest, function (val, key) {
                $scope.model.benhmarkghamlest[key].bechval = $scope.bechval;

            });
    }
    else {
        alert("Please sepecify Bechmark value");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to do this

```
    var projects = [
{
    
    
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
},
{
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
}];

projects.find(data => data.value === "jquery").label ="xxxx"

console.log("------------>",projects)
```

Answer (score -1):

**A short one liner**

**`Also Safe`**

```
(projects.find(pr => pr.value === 'jquery-ui') || {}).desc = 'changed'
```

Answer (score -1):

//lets assume toupdateObjectId == 1

```
const updatedArray =  myArray.map(arr => {
  if (arr.id === toupdateObjectId) {
    return { ...arr, desc: newDesc };
  }
  return arr;
});
console.log(updatedArray)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is my response to the problem. My underscore version was 1.7 hence I could not use `.findIndex`.

So I manually got the index of item and replaced it. Here is the code for the same.

```
 var students = [ 
{id:1,fName:"Ajay", lName:"Singh", age:20, sex:"M" },
{id:2,fName:"Raj", lName:"Sharma", age:21, sex:"M" },
{id:3,fName:"Amar", lName:"Verma", age:22, sex:"M" },
{id:4,fName:"Shiv", lName:"Singh", age:22, sex:"M" }
               ]
```

Below method will replace the student with `id:4` with more attributes in the object

```
function updateStudent(id) {
 var indexOfRequiredStudent = -1;
    _.each(students,function(student,index) {                    
      if(student.id === id) {                        
           indexOfRequiredStudent = index; return;      
      }});
 students[indexOfRequiredStudent] = _.extend(students[indexOfRequiredStudent],{class:"First Year",branch:"CSE"});
```

}

With underscore 1.8 it will be simplified as we have methods `_.findIndexOf`.

Answer (score -2):

Let you want to update value of `array[2] = "data"`

```js
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      if(i == 2){
         array[i] = "data";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a question?

Comment: You successfully updated the 2nd item in that array in the most complicated way possible.