# programmatically add object properties of arrays

Tags: javascript, php, object

```
[
    {
        "uId": "2",
        "tabId": 1,
        "tabName": "Main",
        "points": "10"
    },
    {
        "uId": "3",
        "tabId": 2,
        "tabName": "Photography",
        "points": "20"
    }
]
```

how can I insert into specified array by inspecting its properties values? says I want to add a assoc object into uId = 3, how can I do that? or it's not possible technically?

Comment: answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689856/how-to-change-value-of-object-which-is-inside-an-array-using-javascript-or-jquer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change value of object which is inside an array using javascript or jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689856/how-to-change-value-of-object-which-is-inside-an-array-using-javascript-or-jquer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look like JSON data , so `json_decode()` to an array , search for the `UId` value and then add the corresponding assoc value and after the end finally wrap them up using `json_encode()`

```
foreach($array as $k=>&$arr)
{
    if($arr->{'uId'}==2)
    {
        $arr->{'somecol'}="Hey";
    }
}
echo json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
[
    {
        "uId": "2",
        "tabId": 1,
        "tabName": "Main",
        "points": "10",
        "somecol": "Hey"
    },
    {
        "uId": "3",
        "tabId": 2,
        "tabName": "Photography",
        "points": "20"
    }
]
```

Comment: $array =json_decode($json,true); my $json is already an array, but when I use that it says  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given i

Comment: Then don't do `$array =json_decode($json,true);` , just run the code from the `foreach`

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @user3522444, Please see the edited answer. (Tested)

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible using [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (`Added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition`):

```
array.map(function(i){
    if(i.uId == 3) i['newprop'] = 'newValue';
});
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Czgv7/).

Update: It could be an array

```
if(i.uId == 3) i['newprop'] = ['newvalue1', 'newvalue2'];
```

[Example2 Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Czgv7/1/)

Comment: can 'newValue' be an array?

Comment: Yes, it could be an array @user3522444.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [
    {
        "uId": "2",
        "tabId": 1,
        "tabName": "Main",
        "points": "10"
    },
    {
        "uId": "3",
        "tabId": 2,
        "tabName": "Photography",
        "points": "20"
    }
];

for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    if ( array[i].uId == 3) {
        array[i].someProp = "Hello";
        break; // remove this line for multiple updates
    }
}
```

Or you can make a function like this:

```
function getMatch(data, uid) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        if ( data[i].uId == 3) {
            return data[i];
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
getMatch(array, 3).someproperty = 4;
```

Comment: You can also add `console.log(JSON.stringify(array));` after the for loop to see your updated array

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function, which executes a function on each element of an array

```
a.map(function(el) { 
  if (el.uId == 3) {
    el.prop = "value";
  }
});
```

Or you can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function.

```
// Get the array of object which match the condition
var matches = a.filter(function(x) { return x.uId == 3 });
if (matches.length > 0) {
    matches[0].prop = "value";
}
```

Comment: Sorry but you are a moderator but I didn't notice you in the election but I could be wrong, anyways, welcome :-)