# React - handle change of input with state rendered by iteration through an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my code...

```
    class Module extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super()

            this.state = {
                inputs: [
                    { type: 'text', placeholder: 'placeholder text', name: 'text1', id: 'text1', value: 'aaa' },
                    { type: 'text', placeholder: 'another placeholder text', name: 'text2', id: 'text2', value: '' },
                    { type: 'text', placeholder: 'third placeholder text', name: 'text3', id: 'text3', value: '' },
                ]
            }

            this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
            this.saveModule = this.saveModule.bind(this)
        }

        handleInputChange(event) {
            this.setState ({
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value
            })
        }

        renderInput = (input) => {
            return(
                <div key={ input.id }>
                    <input
                        type={ input.type }
                        name={ input.name }
                        placeholder={ input.placeholder }
                        onBlur={ this.saveModule }
                        value={ input.value }
                        onChange={ this.handleInputChange }
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    { this.state.inputs.map(this.renderInput) }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Module
```

How can i handle change of input which value is rendered from state in this way?!
If i had {this.state.input.value} it works perfectly fine, once I refactor it like this, the setState doesn't seem to reach it anymore.

Any ideas? :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: first you must find the index of the object you will work on. so consider `event.target.name` as the condition to filter the array. then create a new array with the changes. and set the state. heres a good way how to do it http://stackoverflow.com/a/36010124/7744070

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to do the changes directly in `input array` from where you are creating the `input` elements, so you need to do the changes in `onChange` method. Use any **unique property** like name or index to identify which element has been changed, iterate the `input array` find that input element then update the value of that element. After updating the value in input array, update the state input array also, value will automatically reflect in `UI` when `react` re-render the component.

Check the working code:

```js
class Module extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super()

            this.state = {
                inputs: [
                    { type: 'text', placeholder: 'placeholder text', name: 'text1', id: 'text1', value: 'aaa' },
                    { type: 'text', placeholder: 'another placeholder text', name: 'text2', id: 'text2', value: '' },
                    { type: 'text', placeholder: 'third placeholder text', name: 'text3', id: 'text3', value: '' },
                ]
            }

            this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
        }

        handleInputChange(event) {
            let inputs = this.state.inputs.slice();
            for(let i in inputs){
                if(inputs[i].name == event.target.name){
                    inputs[i].value = event.target.value;
                    this.setState ({inputs});
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        renderInput = (input, i) => {
            return(
                <div key={ input.id }>
                    <input
                        type={ input.type }
                        name={ input.name }
                        placeholder={ input.placeholder }
                        onBlur={ this.saveModule }
                        value={ input.value }
                        onChange={ this.handleInputChange }
                    />
                </div>
            )
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    { this.state.inputs.map(this.renderInput) }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }


ReactDOM.render(<Module/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you've done? Replacing a bunch of code with more is not helpful to anyone who might be learning React

Comment: @DarrenSweeney updated the answer with proper information.

Comment: this works magic, thanks a lot and for the explanation, makes sense! :)

Comment: `this.setState ({inputs});` at the end of the day, you are updating the states of ALL the inputs. Is that ok??

Comment: Surely there is a better way to do this than iterating over the whole array? can't you pass the element into the handle function?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the state by creating a new state first.

Since `this.state` is immutable, create a new state by only modifying the old state has to be done by using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) or [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

[This video](https://youtu.be/9M-r8p9ey8U) is a good reference for how to change javascript's object in an immutable way. There is also a library made specifically for creating and modifying immutable objects efficiently called [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

[Refer to this how to use immutable.js with react setState](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Immutable-as-React-state)

(this code has *not* been tested)

```
class Module extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
            inputs: [
                { type: 'text', placeholder: 'placeholder text', name: 'text1', id: 'text1', value: 'aaa' },
                { type: 'text', placeholder: 'another placeholder text', name: 'text2', id: 'text2', value: '' },
                { type: 'text', placeholder: 'third placeholder text', name: 'text3', id: 'text3', value: '' },
            ]
        }

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this)
        this.saveModule = this.saveModule.bind(this)
    }

    // change this to an arrow function
    handleInputChange = (event) =>  {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;
        const oldInputState = this.state.inputs.find(i => i.name === name);
        // use the spread operator or Object.assign to create a brand new state object
        this.setState({
            ...,
            this.state, // copy everything from the old state
            // expect change the `inputs` value
            {inputs: [ // create a brand new array
                ...this.state.inputs.filter(i => i.name !== name),
                {...oldInputState, value} // replace old value with the new value
                // refer to that video I included, it's a great explanation
            ]}
        });
    }

    renderInput = (input) => {
        return(
            <div key={ input.id }>
                <input
                    type={ input.type }
                    name={ input.name }
                    placeholder={ input.placeholder }
                    onBlur={ this.saveModule }
                    value={ input.value }
                    onChange={ this.handleInputChange }
                />
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.inputs.map(this.renderInput) }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Module
```

Good luck!

Comment: i think, using arrow function with `handleInputChange` is not required, he already defined the binding in constructor.