# Replace one element in an Array of Angular model objects with another object using Angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an array of angular objects. I want to replace an entire element in the array with another element.

```
    export interface modelCourse{
         var1: number;
         var2: number;
     }
```

I want to do something like this:

```
    updateResults(myCourse: modelCourse) {
        this.allCourses.forEach(element => {
            if (myCourse.Id=== element.Id) {
                element = myCourse;  // this part doesn't work as expected
            }
        });
    }
```

Where

```
    allCourses: modelCourse[] = [];
```

And allCourses holds all my courses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change value of object which is inside an array using JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689856/how-to-change-value-of-object-which-is-inside-an-array-using-javascript-or-jquer)

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to find the one matching element, you don't need to loop through all of the elements, just use the `findIndex` method. This finds the index of the one element you need without looping through all of them.

You can then use that index to update the original array.

```
updateResults(myCourse: modelCourse) {
    const foundElementIndex = this.allCourses.findIndex(element => myCourse.id === element.id);
    this.allCourses[foundElementIndex] = myCourse;
}
```

I did a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxxddn

Comment: Thanks DeborahK.  However I'm confused on how that replaces the course in my array with myCourse?

Comment: I did a stackblitz. See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `Array.map` to update `this.allCourses`.

```
updateResults(myCourse: modelCourse) {
  this.allCourses = this.allCourses.map(element => {
      if (myCourse.Id === element.Id) {
          return myCourse;
      }
      return element;
  });
}
```