# Need to add an object to an array which is in the state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I need to add an object to the last object of an array

I have an array which contains objects in the state of a class

```
state={
items:[{key:"333",val:"Hi"},{key:"555", val:"Iam"}]
}
```

I need to add a filter object at the the last item object

```
items:[{key:"333",val:"Hi"},{key:"555", val:"Iam",filter:{refine:true}}]
```

I tried the below one

```
    (this.state.items.length-1).concat({filters:{
        refine:true
    }}
```

Comment: What did you try? This seems a pretty simple task. Get the last item from the array, and then add the `filter` key to it.

Comment: How about `ARRAY[ARRAY.length-1]` to access last `item` from `array` ?

Comment: _"I tried the below one"_ - Looks like you should have another look at a JavaScript tutorial on [how to work with arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays).

Comment: "which is in the state" ... so you want to do that in an immutable way?

Comment: I'm guessing that this is related to React's state

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change value of object which is inside an array using JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689856/how-to-change-value-of-object-which-is-inside-an-array-using-javascript-or-jquer)

Comment: @giorgim it might be related to reactjs but the question can still independently hold

Comment: Yes it is related to react js

Comment: @Jagrati Author said it is react related, so the tag needs to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply access the last object using `index` method of array, modify it and update the state array

```js
let state={
    items:[{key:"333",val:"Hi"},{key:"555", val:"Iam"}]
}
let last = state.items[state.items.length - 1];
last = {...last, filter:{refine:true}};

const newState = {
  ...state,
  items: [
      ...state.items.slice(0, -1),
      last
  ]
}

console.log(newState);
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Instead of `state.items[state.items.length - 1];`, you can try `state.items.pop()`. That saves you from slicing again. Also, yes it will mutate the `state.items`, but you are anyways setting new state, so should not have that big impact

Answer (score -1):

You can take the last element and than merge obj to it and than add it to end of array again

```js
let state={items:[{key:"333",val:"Hi"},{key:"555", val:"Iam"}]}

let obj = {filter:{refine:true}}

let add = (initial,obj) => {
  let last = initial[initial.length-1]
  let arr = [...initial].slice(0,-2)
  return [...initial, {...last, ...obj}]
}
state.items = add(state.items,obj)

console.log(state)
```

Answer (score -1):

With some small helpers ....

```
 const lens = (key, fn) => obj => ({ ...obj, [key]: fn(obj[key]) });
 const mapIndex = (index, fn) => arr => arr.map((it, i) => i === (index + arr.length) % arr.length ? fn(it) : it);
```

it is as easy as:

```
 this.setState(lens("items", mapIndex(-1, it => ({ ...it, filter: { refine: true }}))));
```