# Edit a set of objects using localStorage

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage, javascript-objects

Not sure where to start with this one...  I'm creating a basic todo app, using localStorage.  (I specially, am not using a backend database).

So far, I can update and display, the objects I have stored locally.  And I am displaying them on my page.

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Set object
    let data = {
      name: nameInput.value,
      url: urlInput.value
    };
    bookMarksArray.push(data);
    console.log("Added bookmark #" + data);

    // Saving
    localStorage.setItem("bookMarksArray", JSON.stringify(bookMarksArray));
});
```

However, I also want to able to **edit**, each item in my DOM.  Once edited, I want that specific object, which correlates to this, to be updated in **localStorage**.

**How do I do this?**

I'm not sure where to start.  Here's a codepen, of my code so far:
https://codepen.io/ReenaVerma1981/pen/LYEPbjL

EG 
- if I want to update a URL value to www.google.co.uk
- And this is updated, in the correct object, in localStorage

Here's some psuedo code, is this a good approach?

```
// List each object as an individual form in DOM
// So I can easily update the input.value, (with a new value)
// The **edit** button, would be a submit button
// Or there's an eventHandler on this button
// Which onClick, takes the input.value, (either name.value or url.value)
// Identifies whether these values, match values in the localStorage object
// And if so, get the object index
// Then update these object values, based on the object index?
// Update localStorage via localStorage.setItem
```

**Here's some example code, I'm writing, to try and do this:**

```
    // UPDATE/EDIT EXISTING
const list = document.querySelector('.url-list');
list.addEventListener('click', event => {

  if (event.target.classList.contains('js-edit-url')) {
    console.log('edit');
    const editName = event.target.parentElement.name.value;
    const editURL = event.target.parentElement.url.value;

    let data = {
      name: editName,
      url: editURL
    };

    Object.keys(bookMarksArray).map(function (old_key, index) {
      // console.log('old_key',old_key);
      let new_key = data;
      console.log('data', data);
      if (old_key !== new_key) {
        Object.defineProperty(bookMarksArray, new_key,
          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(bookMarksArray, old_key));
          // console.log('bookMarksArray',bookMarksArray);
          // localStorage.setItem("bookMarksArray", JSON.stringify(bookMarksArray));
        delete bookMarksArray[old_key];
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you narrow down your question? Which of the last three steps are you having trouble implementing?

Comment: @Cristy - Well basically, I want to know how I can edit, each item from my local storage. But I'm not sure how to do this....  The psuedo code, was just an example, of how I'm not sure how to approach this.

Comment: @ReenaVerma you have to `localStorage.getItem()`, mutate it, and then `localStorage.setItem()` again

Comment: @symlink - Thanks for this, but I wasn't sure on how to break this down. I have added some psuedo code.

Comment: It's pretty much what symlink says while replacing `mutate it` with the edited input of the user... What's unclear?

Comment: @Trace - Not sure exactly how I'm suppose to "mutate" it?  I get, I need to update the object, but I'm not sure how to write this bit of code or at least break it down. "Mutate it" is a bit vague, as I haven't really done that before... any help would be apprecaited.

Comment: Well you get the json from localstorage, change the values in it that the user updated, and then put it back. Or just re-save the entire json. However you want it.

Comment: @Trace - Yes I know, that bit I'm not sure on. LOL.

Comment: You mean the json transformation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203358/discussion-between-trace-and-reena-verma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

I found a [really good example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689856/how-to-change-value-of-object-which-is-inside-an-array-using-javascript-or-jquer), using the ES6 way, without mutating original data:

```
// UPDATE/EDIT EXISTING
const list = document.querySelector('.url-list');
list.addEventListener('click', event => {

  if (event.target.classList.contains('js-edit-url')) {
    console.log('edit');
    const editName = event.target.parentElement.name.value;
    const editURL = event.target.parentElement.url.value;

    // Find the object index, by looping through and matching name.value
    const objIndex = bookMarksArray.findIndex(obj => obj.name === editName);

    // make new object of updated object.   
    const updatedObj = { ...bookMarksArray[objIndex], url: editURL};

    // make final new array of objects by combining updated object.
    const updatedProjects = [
      ...bookMarksArray.slice(0, objIndex),
      updatedObj,
      ...bookMarksArray.slice(objIndex + 1),
    ];


    localStorage.setItem("bookMarksArray", JSON.stringify(updatedProjects));
  }
});
```