# In an array of objects, how to update (not just find) the object having property X equal to Y?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

My array of objects contains objects of different kinds, meaning they can have very different properties. However they all share an `id` property.

When my app's user wants to update one of these objects, I need to find that object in the array based on the `id` and update all its properties, probably using `Object.assign()`.

I know how to find and return the object I want based on the `id`, but not how to update it as well. Any idea?

```
let myArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'john',
    age: '22',
    position: 'developer'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'james',
    age: '31',
    position: 'designer'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'david',
    age: '45',
    position: 'teacher'
  }
]

let updateForJames = {
    age: '38',
    position: 'project manager'
}

let JamesId = 2

Object.assign(myArray, {
    // ...
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rdj9h8y/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change value of object which is inside an array using JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689856/how-to-change-value-of-object-which-is-inside-an-array-using-javascript-or-jquer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy with changing the array *in-place* you can use `.find()` to find the object with the given id, and then update that object using `Object.assign()` like so:

```js
const myArray = [{ id: 1, name: 'john', age: '22', position: 'developer' }, { id: 2, name: 'james', age: '31', position: 'designer' }, { id: 1, name: 'david', age: '45', position: 'teacher' }];
const updateForJames = {
  age: '38',
  position: 'project manager'
}
const JamesId = 2;

const jamesobj = myArray.find(({id}) => id === JamesId) || {};
Object.assign(jamesobj, updateForJames);
console.log(myArray);
```

Alternatively, if you want to get a new array (rather than modifying it in place) you can `.map()` each object to a new object, and add the new contents in `updateForJames` when James's id appears using the spread syntax:

```js
const myArray = [{ id: 1, name: 'john', age: '22', position: 'developer' }, { id: 2, name: 'james', age: '31', position: 'designer' }, { id: 1, name: 'david', age: '45', position: 'teacher' }];
const updateForJames = {
  age: '38',
  position: 'project manager'
};
const JamesId = 2;

const newArray = myArray.map((person) => person.id === JamesId 
  ? {...person, ...updateForJames} 
  : person
);
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works however I don't understand why: I'm using first option as I need to change the array in place, but you're using `Object.assign()` on `jamesobj` not on the array in place, so how can the latter be modified? I dont' get it

Comment: So `.find()` returns a reference to the object inside the array. This means when you change a property on this reference you're actually changing the object inside the array. `Object.assign()` allows us to change multiple properties at once in the reference (and thus the object inside the array)

Comment: So it's a similar idea to what's happening [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ws5q3gtj/), just `Object.assign()` allows us to change multiple properties at once on the reference rather than just one property at a time

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now I got it :)

Comment: @drake035 no worries ;)

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing that code though, could you kindly take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/phrw0j7u/ and see why the incorrect object get updated please? (also I don't understand something: if I display the array BEFORE making the change, it STILL displays the change. To prevent this, I need to wait 2 seconds before making the change and only then the first display correctly shows shows the array as it was before the change)

Comment: You're missing the `id ==` in your `.find()` function. https://jsfiddle.net/wf28gs3q/

Comment: basically, when the the `find` function loops through every object in the array. For each object we pull out its `id` property (using destructuring assignment). Then we check if it is equal to the wanted (in your case the string id). When the inner function returns `true` it returns a reference to the current object it is iterated on

Comment: @drake035 the issue with the array changing before you make the change is because the console itself doesn't log a "snapshot" of the array like you might think. Instead, it logs a reference to the array. This we change the array in place, you'll see both change. It's explained better [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429203/weird-behavior-with-objects-console-log)

Comment: What a stupid omission from me, sorry for that. Works now and I also see now the reason behind that weirdness in the console. Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

Comment: @drake035 no worries. One way you can get around the reference issue (and if you want to log a "snapshot" of the current state) is to use `JSON.stringify()` on your array ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/wf28gs3q/1/) is an example)