# Create a JavaScript object without repeating

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

I'm trying to create a JavaScript object that should be processed by a PHP API.

It should look like this:

```
[{
  'targetId': 'roof',
  'color': 'red'
},
{
  'targetId': 'window',
  'color': 'green'
}]
```

the values should be generated on user input, e.g each time a the user clicks an element called "roof", it will loop through some colors, same for "window" (+ multiple others).

What I have right now is this:

```js
let requestJSON = []
let timeout = undefined

myElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let target = e.target;
    let targetID = target.id
    let color = colors[getNumber(e.target)]
    target.setAttribute('fill', color)
    let thisJSON = 
    {
        'targetId': targetID,
        'color': color
    }
    updateRequest(thisJSON)
})

function updateRequest(input) {
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout)
    requestJSON.push(input)
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(requestJSON)
        // makeRequest(requestJSON)
    }, 1000);
}

function makeRequest(body) {
    body = JSON.stringify(body)
    fetch('https://myapi.com/setcolor', {
        body: body,
        method: 'POST'
    })
    .then((res) => {
        return console.log(res.json())
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
    })
}
```

Currently, this will push the same element to the JavaScript object multiple times, even if it already exists.

What I need to achieve is that there shouldn't be any repeating values inside my JavaScript object: before the element is pushed to the array, the function should check if the `targetId` already exists and only update the corresponding value.

What would be the right approach here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Array#find` might be useful here. Given the right callback, it'll find the object with the matching `targetId`, which you can then update directly (eg. `match.color = color;`) since the object will be by-reference. If `match` isn't found, you can handle that situation by adding it to the array.

Comment: first things first `thisJSON` is not JSON, it's a Javascript object

Comment: @Liam absolutely true!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol will try, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check if the Object with given `targetId` already exists. So, make the following changes to `updateRequest(input)`:

```
function updateRequest(input) {
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout)
    let obj = requestJSON.find(elem=>elem.targetId === input.targetId)
    // If targetId already exists in requestJSON, update color, else push
    if(obj)
        obj.color = input.color
    else
        requestJSON.push(input)
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(requestJSON)
        // makeRequest(requestJSON)
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: this is \*almost\* what i'm after. It skips the element when it already exists, but I want it to update with a new value instead

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: works like a charm, thanks! another approach would have been to use `findIndex` as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41938641/10727821