# How to take a dynamic input inside a findIndex callback function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/41938641/:

```js
let myArray = [
  {id: 0, name: "Jhon"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
],
    
//Find index of specific object using findIndex method.    
objIndex = myArray.findIndex((obj => obj.id == 1));

//Log object to Console.
console.log("Before update: ", myArray[objIndex])

//Update object's name property.
myArray[objIndex].name = "Laila"

//Log object to console again.
console.log("After update: ", myArray[objIndex])
```

```
//Find index of specific object using findIndex method.    
    objIndex = myArray.findIndex((obj => obj.id == 1));
```

As you can see, in this code I have `obj.id == 1`.

I want to take it dynamically, not hardcoded. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable in place of `1` inside the findIndex callback

```js
function modifyObj() {
  let myArray = [
    {id: 0, name: "Jhon"},
    {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
    {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
    {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
  ]
  
  let id = document.getElementById('myInput').value
  

  //Find index of specific object using findIndex method.    
  objIndex = myArray.findIndex((obj => obj.id == id));

  //Log object to Console.
  console.log("Before update: ", myArray[objIndex])

  //Update object's name property.
  myArray[objIndex].name = "Laila"

  //Log object to console again.
  console.log("After update: ", myArray[objIndex])
  
 }
```

```html
<label>Modify obj</label>
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="1">
<input type="button" value="Modify" onClick="modifyObj()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myArray = [
  {id: 0, name: "Jhon"},
  {id: 1, name: "Sara"},
  {id: 2, name: "Domnic"},
  {id: 3, name: "Bravo"}
]

const id = prompt('Enter the id of the element;')
    
//Find index of specific object using findIndex method.    
objIndex = myArray.findIndex((obj => obj.id == id));

//Log object to Console.
console.log("Before update: ", myArray[objIndex])

//Update object's name property.
myArray[objIndex].name = "Laila"

//Log object to console again.
console.log("After update: ", myArray[objIndex])
```

I simply used the `prompt` function to show a model where you can provide the id. Run the snippet to check the result.