# How to work in Vue.js data table with huge amount of data from GCP Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, quasar-framework

After having watched numerous videos about GCP Firestore, I'm still asking myself what is a best way to work with huge amount of data coming from Firestore ?

Like 800 000 products, I would like to display all of them in such [datatable with Quasar](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table):

How do I make it work in real-time, like listening for each item's changes without having exceeded my quota usage to avoid pay high bills for stupid code ?

Backend:

```
app.get('/products/get', async (req, res) => {
  const snapshot = await db.collection('products3P').limit(20).get()

  const result = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())

  res.json(result)
})
```

Frontend:

```
<q-table title="Products"
  :rows="rows"
  :columns="columns"
  :filter="filter"
  row-key="name"
  no-data-label="No results"
/>

// Fetching results from backend once page is loaded:
api.get('/api/products/get').then(({ data }) => {
  data.forEach(i => {
    rows.value.push({
      name: i.name,
      sku: i.sku,
      model: i.model,
      brand: i.brand,
      description: i.description
    })
  })
})
```

Binance's Market page is a perfect example, what is the best solutions to make datatables efficient ?

Any links or suggestions will be highly appreciate.

Comment: Do you have your own servers between the end user and Firebase?

Comment: Right now yes, it goes like this: 1. Front request Backend, 2. Backend requests Firestore. I'm thinking about the request the Firestore data directly from Frontend.

Answer (score 1):

You can [paginate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) and show only 20 (or the amount you prefer) items at a time. When the user changes the page load the next set of items and show them. Quasar has a [loading state](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table#loading-state) in their tables which you can use while the next documents are loading for the first time.

To show realtime updates, you can [listen](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) to documents of those 20 items only.

```
db.collection("products3P").orderBy("somefield")
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const products = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            products.push(doc.data().name);
        });
        console.log("Current products: ", products.join(", "));
        // Update the Table
    });
```

You can set that array (of objects) to that table `(rows.values)` and render the data. You can make sure the changes are just current documents being updated and not new one's being added (if you want to) by checking the [change type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).

```
querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
  if (change.type === "modified") {
    console.log("Modified product: ", change.doc.data());
  }
  // else don't update in that array
})
```

To update the changes in existing array (rows), you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41938641/13130697) to update an item in array.

*Do note that your server is not involved in this process.* If you need to do this through your servers then you'll have to use web sockets but using Firestore directly as shown above is definitely easier. Also make sure you [detach listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) of the previous products.

Comment: I will give that a shot, thank you for your answer