# How to push the values inside array object using spread in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to change/update the data inside an array, but it gives me error, please see the below code,

```js
let array = [{
  name: "lol",
  age: "15",
  address: {
    street: "ABC street",
    road: "123"
  }
}]
const onChange = (props, value) => {
  console.log({ ...array,
    [props]: value
  })
  // it works for name,age but not working for street or road
  // if i pass street as a props it should update street property alone
}
onChange("street", 10);
//its adding another node instead of updating the address.streat object
```

Comment: yes i made the snippet runnable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change value of object which is inside an array using JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689856/how-to-change-value-of-object-which-is-inside-an-array-using-javascript-or-jquer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's adding another node because you're using a spread operator on an array so it's converting that array into an object property by index.
I have slightly updated the code. Hope it'll solve your problem.

```
let array = [{
  name: "lol",
  age: "15",
  address: {
    street: "ABC street",
    road: "123"
  }
}]
const onChange = (props, value) => {
  if(props==="street"||props==="road"){
    console.log({ ...array[0],
    address:{
        ...array[0].address,
        [props]: value
    }
  })
  }else {
    console.log({ ...array[0],
        [props]: value
      })
  }
}
```