# change the value of object inside a list

Tags: javascript, list

My code's output is like this:

```
let myArray = [{"num": "2", "name": "Jhon"}, {"num": "1", "name": "Sara"}, {"num": "2", "name": "Domnic"}, {"num": "3", "name": "Bravo"}]
```

How can I access value of `num` in each field of the list and if `num: 2`, change its value to `5`?

Comment: You would like to iterate the list (for example, map), check the value of num each time, and modify if it's 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change value of object which is inside an array using JavaScript or jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689856/how-to-change-value-of-object-which-is-inside-an-array-using-javascript-or-jquer)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let myArray = [{
  "num": "2",
  "name": "Jhon"
}, {
  "num": "1",
  "name": "Sara"
}, {
  "num": "2",
  "name": "Domnic"
}, {
  "num": "3",
  "name": "Bravo"
}]

const result = myArray.map(({...item}) => {
  if (item.num == 2)
    item.num = "5"
  return item
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Instead of `item.num = 5` it should be `item.num = "5"` because `num` was `string` not `int`

Comment: I received this error: `TypeError: myArray.map is not a function`

Comment: @Lars Do not use `Array.map` like this. This will create a new array aswell as modifies the existing array.

Comment: @helen In which environment are you running your app? Browser, Node? Which version are you using?

Comment: @Nitheesh True, updated! And upvoted yours!

Comment: @LarsFlieger You could have tried a different solution rather than using my same approach.

Comment: @Nitheesh There are several approaches to do this however I think spreading the item in the parameters is the simplest one. That's why I decided to take your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.forEach` to change the original Array

```js
let myArray = [{ "num": "2", "name": "Jhon" }, { "num": "1", "name": "Sara" }, { "num": "2", "name": "Domnic" }, { "num": "3", "name": "Bravo" }]
myArray.forEach((node) => node.num = node.num == "2" ? "5" : node.num);
console.log(myArray);
```

If you want to create a new array from the existing one, Use `Array.map`

```js
let myArray = [{ "num": "2", "name": "Jhon" }, { "num": "1", "name": "Sara" }, { "num": "2", "name": "Domnic" }, { "num": "3", "name": "Bravo" }]
const newArray = myArray.map(({ ...node }) => node.num = node.num == "2" ? "5" : node.num);
console.log(newArray);
```

**Please Note:** Do not forget to use spread syntax (`{ ...node }`) else your original array will be modified here.